# Image stored in external resource DLL

Tags: wpf

No, it's not just another question about pack URIs. :-)

I have a resource DLL external to the application to store branding data. It stores a `BitmapImage` in its `ResourceDictionary` (note that the original image filename will be different for each brand, hence for each DLL):

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="Logo" UriSource="Resources/changing-vendorname.png" />
```

In the main application, I read the external DLL and obtain various resources from it, inlcuding the vendor logo:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(BrandDllPath);
var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/BrandDll;component/Themes/Generic.xaml");
var VendorLogo = (BitmapImage)dict["Logo"];
```

When I examine this `VendorLogo` variable, it contains the `BitmapImage` just as expected. Still, when I want to display it in an `Image` control:

```
Image.Source = VendorLogo;
```

I get nothing. No error message, just nothing displays.

Actually, the same thing happens if I put the resource among my own using:

```
Application.Current.Resources["Logo"] = (BitmapImage)dict["Logo"];
```

and try to use it from XAML:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource Logo}" />
```

I do the same with lots of different resources, strings, colors (practically theming the application), everything works, except the images.

Comment: What if you put the assembly name in the original URI, like `UriSource="pack://application:,,,/BrandDll;component/Resources/vendorname.png"`.

Comment: No. That's why I started with the sentence I started it with. :-) I don't know the original name. There will be hundreds of different brand DLLs, each with their own referenced images. That's why it has been put into a dictionary and assigned a generic key. Updated the question to stress this.

Comment: I've tested this, and for me it works with a full Pack URI for the original image `UriSource`.

Comment: Yes, it sure does. The problem is *without* the full pack URI. The basic tenet of branding or theming is that you reference to the *same* items all the time, only change their underlying contents.

Comment: The full pack uri is **local** to the resource assembly, e.g. `pack://application:,,,/SomeVendorsDll;component/Resourc‌​es/some-vendor-name.png`. It's not externally visible.

Comment: Well, it does. But you gave me an idea that does work, I'll put it into an answer.

Comment: Since Generic.xaml is in a subfolder, a relative URI like `UriSource=../Resources/vendorname.png"` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Clemens gave me an idea that could be turned into a working solution. Instead of

```
var VendorLogo = (BitmapImage)dict["Logo"];
```

we have a multi-step process that gets the original image name and uses it:

```
var logo = (BitmapImage)dict["Logo"];
string uri = "pack://application:,,,/BrandDll;component/" + logo.UriSource;
var VendorLogo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
// or
Application.Current.Resources["Logo"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
```

and using it like this:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource Logo}" />
```